# Map array of objects to object of key value pairs

Tags: arrays, json, object, jq

I have the following JSON structure:

```json
[
 {
   "key11": "value11",
   "key12": "value12",
   "key13": "value13",
   "key14": "value14"
 },
 {
   "key21": "value21",
   "key22": "value22",
   "key23": "value23",
   "key24": "value24"
 },
 {
   "key31": "value31",
   "key32": "value32",
   "key33": "value33",
   "key34": "value34"
 }
]
```

How do I convert it to the following structure:

```json
{
  "value11": "value12",
  "value21": "value22", 
  "value31": "value32"
}
```

I have tried a few JQ operators, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let data = [
    {
      "key11": "value11",
      "key12": "value12",
      "key13": "value13",
      "key14": "value14"
    },
    {
      "key21": "value21",
      "key22": "value22",
      "key23": "value23",
      "key24": "value24"
    },
    {
      "key31": "value31",
      "key32": "value32",
      "key33": "value33",
      "key34": "value34"
    }
   ];
   
   //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
   let result = data.reduce((acc,next) => {
        let [first_val,second_val] = Object.values(next);
        acc[first_val] = second_val;
        return acc;
   },{});

   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but the question is about JQ, not Javascript

Comment: Sorry! i thought it was jquery! thnx

Answer (score 0):

> is there an option to use a string as index instead of a numeric index?

Yes, you could, for example, read the string keys as arguments, and resolve them in an iterative (or mapping) context.

One way would be to `reduce` the input into an initially empty output object `{}`, using the key of `to_entries` to access the iteration index, which in turn can be used to index into the argument list:

```bash
jq 'reduce to_entries[] as {$key, $value} ({};
  $ARGS.positional[$key *2:] as [$k, $v] | .[$value[$k]] = $value[$v]
)' input.json --args key11 key12 key21 key22 key31 key32
```

With this effort, however, you could also just map the input array, and use `from_entries` to generate the output object, enabling you to use the `with_entries` shortcut:

```bash
jq 'with_entries(
  $ARGS.positional[.key *2:] as [$k, $v] | {key:.value[$k], value:.value[$v]}
)' input.json --args key11 key12 key21 key22 key31 key32
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm sorry, my initial JSON structure was wrong: Each object in the array has the same keys.

So, assuming your input with all objects having the same keys looks like

```json
[
  {
    "key1": "value11",
    "key2": "value12",
    "key3": "value13",
    "key4": "value14"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value21",
    "key2": "value22",
    "key3": "value23",
    "key4": "value24"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value31",
    "key2": "value32",
    "key3": "value33",
    "key4": "value34"
  }
]
```

Then, you could either use `map` to turn each array item to a single-field object, and then `add` to combine these objects into one ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/J-BW2nCRLon)):

```bash
jq 'map({(.key1): .key2}) | add' input.json
```

Or you could `reduce` the array's items into an initially empty output object `{}` by iteratively setting another of its keys ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eqhRNYclfP8)):

```bash
jq 'reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.key1] = $i.key2)' input.json
```

Both approaches return:

```json
{
  "value11": "value12",
  "value21": "value22",
  "value31": "value32"
}
```